# Directory length not working

Tags: c#, file, directory

This may be a stupid question but im trying to find out how many files are in a folder and one minuite its telling me 0 and the next time its telling me 1 when there is simply no files there.

I even made a new folder called H in my documents with nothing in there at all and its still coming back 1 item. someone please explain this or even try it yourself, its hurting my head

```
int i = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\William\Documents\H\").Length;
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(i));
```

Comment: Try having it display the file that it's finding. Maybe that will help?

Comment: Have you tried to output what `GetFiles` actually returns somewhere? Its hard to see how it can suddenly change

Comment: how would i do this? im not that good at programming

Comment: Well, `GetFiles(...)` already returns an array of files found. Just loop through that array an output what it finds.

Comment: Btw, are you sure it's not a auto-generated (perhaps hidden) system file like `thumbs.db`?

Comment: : `foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\William\Documents\H\")) MessageBox.Show(file);`

Comment: oh yes it came up as thumbs.db. but other times when ive tried it, it shows the lengh as 0 instead of 1. is there code that would see the lengh of the actualy files and not thumbs.db

Comment: Make a new console application and just use a foreach loop to iterate over `GetFiles` for that directory

Comment: It sounds like you are looking to add a search pattern for which there is a different [GetFiles override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Printout files itself, e.g. `MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\William\Documents\H\")));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So actually you get unwanted system files like `thumbs.db`. You can exclude them in this way:

```
string[] files = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\William\Documents\H\").GetFiles()
            .Where(f => !f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System | FileAttributes.Hidden))
            .Select(f => f.FullName)
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: Beat me to it! I was gonna put `... !f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System | FileAttributes.Hidden))` to exclude hidden files as well.

Comment: I would just be careful (to anyone else who might use this method). Obviously this is going to depend on your situation, but if you might want hidden files, simply exclude that portion.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely you have a hidden file that is being counted. Check for hidden files like thumbs.db or other system files that might be there.

Comment: yes its thumbs, i think this will work now 
[code]
int i = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\William\Documents\H\").Length;
            if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\William\Documents\H\Thumbs.db")) { i -= 1; }
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString (i));
[/code]

Comment: @TimSchmelter above has a great solution for you. I'd accept that one as the answer and use the code he presented.  Checking for Thumbs.db specifically isn't the best way to go.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this one:

```
System.IO.Directory myDir = GetMyDirectoryForTheExample();
int count = myDir.GetFiles().Length;
```

Comment: I guess you mean `DirectoryInfo` instead of the static utility class `Directory`. But why do you think that `Directory` returns the wrong files and `DirectoryInfo` not?

Comment: This isn't an answer. I get that you can't comment, but posting this is only going to get you further from that privilege.